# When bending a plane from Import Image as Plane plugin I can see the other side of the image

Tags: mesh, texturing, normals

When I take a plane from Import Images as Plane and then bend it so that it overlaps, I'm able to see the other side. I'm not sure how to prevent this behavior from happening:

[image: problem I'm having]

To recreate the problem:

1. Use Import Images as Plane to import an image
2. Subdivide the surface a few times
3. Bend the plane inward (sort of like how a flower blooms but backward)

Things I tried:

1. Recalculating the normals
2. Unwrapping the image
3. Texture coordinate and mapping nodes (tried from UV and from object)

I'm using Blender 3.4. Thanks!

Comment: in the shader editor add an input geometry node. connect the back facing as a factor to a mix color node. you can then either set a fixed color for the back facing or use it as an alpha map. Alternatively on the materials tab > settings > backface culling.

Comment: @Ratt So I tried `materials tab → settings → backface culling` and got an odd result, sort of the inverse of what I needed, but then I realized that `materials tab → settings → show backface` was checked, so I unchecked it and now I get the desired behavior. Thank you for putting me in the right direction. :)

Comment: Note: If you want this to work with alpha in the nodes, you need to change the blend mode to `alpha clip` in `materials tab → settings`.

Comment: If you got an odd result like the inverse of what you needed, then probably the face normals were pointing in the opposite direction of what they should have.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I looked at the normals and they seemed okay, I also tried recalculating my normals a few times and flipping them manually in case for some reason what I was seeing wasn't accurate.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Note: I've been told that this answer might only apply to Eevee in cases where there's not a smooth transparency gradient. This question could use a better answer, but this may work for you.</sub>

This is what worked for me:

1. Click the mesh
2. Go to the *Material* tab

[image]

3. Scroll down to *Settings* and change the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Clip*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I see in your question is backface culling. What you provide as answer is how to use textures with alpha transparency in _Eevee_ - so that's not really an answer to your initial problem. Switching to _Alpha Clip_ without disabling _Backface Culling_ would most probably not have worked. And note: _Alpha Clip_ will work good on textures where you want the parts to be either transparent or opaque. If you have a gradient alpha going from transparent to opaque, _Alpha Clip_ will not provide good results.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hmm, I had backface culling unchecked and I was still getting the same problem. What fixed it for me (until I needed to add alpha) was `material tab → settings → unchecking "show backface". Thanks for the advice on the gradients on alpha clip though, is there a mode that works well with the alpha gradients?

Comment: You are mixing things up... your initial question didn't mention any alpha transparency, there the problem was clearly backface culling. Recalculating normals cannot "fix it", because no matter in which direction the normals are pointing, one side is always the backface. When you introduced alpha transparency, then you got another issue because by default _Eevee_ does not show it. And when you enable some kind of transparency, it looks differently depending on if _Backface Culling_ is enabled or not and then _Show Backface_ (which is only available for _Alpha Blend_) will also change the look.

Comment: So if someone had the same problem as your initial question without transparency, this answer does not provide a solution since you are just focusing on the _Alpha Blend Modes_ here. Sure, they have some part in what you have to do to make it look correct, but your answer gives a solution to a problem which was not part of the question and will not help people that do not use transparency. For your question which works best with alpha gradients, I guess it's _Alpha Blend_. But to be honest, for transparency, transmission, reflections and light bounces I do not like _Eevee_. I use _Cycles_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Maybe you could post an answer to elucidate on some of this? I like Eevee because realism isn't really part of my rendering, and I make animations so it's helpful for quick rendering. I am by no means a Blender expert. Every once in awhile I do use cycles though, is there a clear-cut easy way to make the same effect work in cycles? Or maybe it just works by default?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Also the reason that transparency was not included in my original question was to make recreating the problem a little bit simpler, and I discovered that the first thing I tried that worked for zero transparency did not work with images with transparency, and I found that my answer works for these two cases in Eevee.

Comment: Yes, in _Cycles_ it just works by default. That's it, you do not have to switch between blend modes, backface culling etc., don't have to turn on reflections, refractions or have to figure out how to get good shadows... so I don't use _Eevee_ and I'm by no means the one to give a good _Eevee_ related answer. And it's not that your answer is not working - I just said the _Blend Mode_ is only relevant if you use transparency, while you not even mention backface culling in your answer which was very relevant to the original question.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Okay, thanks